# Use Custom Numbers in Flash Game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

Hello!
I am making a 8bit game, where I basically want to use old-school solutions for different things.

How can I use custom numbers (for example png-files of 0-9) instead of the regular font to show score and etc? For example; I have seen the sprite sheet of *Flappy Bird*, where there were custom number, which were used. I know I can use other fonts, but if this is possible, I think I will find this most satisfying for this project.

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you already tried something ? Of course you can use images (from your library) or simply embedding a font for your digits like fonts [here](http://www.dafont.com/fr/theme.php?cat=302&fpp=100&psize=l&text=2015) or [here](http://www.dafont.com/fr/theme.php?cat=301&fpp=100&psize=l&text=2015) ... Try to write something and then put your code here if you have always the problem.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, but that's because I don't really know how. I know I can use fonts, that's easy, but I don't know how I can make the different images replace the score. For example: I have a score of 24, I want the image of "2" and the image of "4" displayed. It should also update, so that when I get I point, it will automatically replace the "4" (in 24) with "5" (in 25).

Comment: If you know using fonts, so show us what you can do ! For images, you can find digits images like [here](https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=iconset%3AKeyamoon-IcoMoon--limited+seg), add it to your project library, and then use them as you like ... try to do it and then we can help you if you have problems ... just try to do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the number to a `String` and split the resulting `String` so you can manage each individual digit.

For example...

```
var str:String = String(myNumber);
var strList:Array = str.split("");
for(var i:int = 0; i < strList.length; i++)
{
    //add visual representation of strList[i] to DisplayList
}
```

Store an `Array` that links each numerical digit (0-9) with its corresponding `DisplayObject`.